# Magento override community with local extension

Tags: php, class, magento, extends

I want to extend a magento core class and override a function in it. 
A community extension use the same class and override my code, but normally a local one overrides a community one or am I wrong?

Here is my extension which works fine in a clean install:

app/etc/modules/NameSpace_OutOfStockLabel.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <NameSpace_OutOfStockLabel>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </NameSpace_OutOfStockLabel>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/NameSpace/OutOfStockLabel/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <NameSpace_OutOfStockLabel>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </NameSpace_OutOfStockLabel>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_view_type_configurable>NameSpace_OutOfStockLabel_Block_Configurable</product_view_type_configurable>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/NameSpace/OutOfStockLabel/Block/Configurable.php

```
<?php

class NameSpace_OutOfStockLabel_Block_Configurable extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable
{
    /**
     * Get Allowed Products
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowProducts()
    {
        if (!$this->hasAllowProducts()) {
            $products = array();
            $skipSaleableCheck = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getSkipSaleableCheck();
            $allProducts = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
                ->getUsedProducts(null, $this->getProduct());
            foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
                //if ($product->isSaleable() || $skipSaleableCheck) {
                    $products[] = $product;
                //}
            }
            $this->setAllowProducts($products);
        }
        return $this->getData('allow_products');
    }

    /**
     * Composes configuration for js
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getJsonConfig()
    {
        $attributes = array();
        $options    = array();
        $store      = $this->getCurrentStore();
        $taxHelper  = Mage::helper('tax');
        $currentProduct = $this->getProduct();

        $preconfiguredFlag = $currentProduct->hasPreconfiguredValues();
        if ($preconfiguredFlag) {
            $preconfiguredValues = $currentProduct->getPreconfiguredValues();
            $defaultValues       = array();
        }

        foreach ($this->getAllowProducts() as $product) {
            $productId  = $product->getId();

            foreach ($this->getAllowAttributes() as $attribute) {
                $productAttribute   = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
                $productAttributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
                $attributeValue     = $product->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());

                $options['quantity'][$product -> getAttributeText($productAttribute->getName())] = $product->getIsInStock();
                if (!isset($options[$productAttributeId])) {
                    $options[$productAttributeId] = array();
                }

                if (!isset($options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue])) {
                    $options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue] = array();
                }
                $options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue][] = $productId;
            }
        }

        $this->_resPrices = array(
            $this->_preparePrice($currentProduct->getFinalPrice())
        );

        foreach ($this->getAllowAttributes() as $attribute) {
            $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
            $attributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
            $info = array(
               'id'        => $productAttribute->getId(),
               'code'      => $productAttribute->getAttributeCode(),
               'label'     => $attribute->getLabel(),
               'options'   => array()
            );

            $optionPrices = array();
            $prices = $attribute->getPrices();
            if (is_array($prices)) {
                foreach ($prices as $value) {
                    if(!$this->_validateAttributeValue($attributeId, $value, $options)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $currentProduct->setConfigurablePrice(
                        $this->_preparePrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent'])
                    );
                    $currentProduct->setParentId(true);
                    Mage::dispatchEvent(
                        'catalog_product_type_configurable_price',
                        array('product' => $currentProduct)
                    );
                    $configurablePrice = $currentProduct->getConfigurablePrice();

                    if (isset($options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']])) {
                        $productsIndex = $options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']];
                    } else {
                        $productsIndex = array();
                    }

                    $info['options'][] = array(
                        'id'        => $value['value_index'],
                        'label'     => ($options['quantity'][$value['label']] <= 0) ? $value['label'] . ' (Out of Stock)' : $value['label'],
                        'price'     => $configurablePrice,
                        'oldPrice'  => $this->_prepareOldPrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                        'products'  => $productsIndex,
                        'IsInStock' => $options['quantity'][$value['label']]
                    );
                    $optionPrices[] = $configurablePrice;
                }
            }
            /**
             * Prepare formated values for options choose
             */
            foreach ($optionPrices as $optionPrice) {
                foreach ($optionPrices as $additional) {
                    $this->_preparePrice(abs($additional-$optionPrice));
                }
            }
            if($this->_validateAttributeInfo($info)) {
               $attributes[$attributeId] = $info;
            }

            // Add attribute default value (if set)
            if ($preconfiguredFlag) {
                $configValue = $preconfiguredValues->getData('super_attribute/' . $attributeId);
                if ($configValue) {
                    $defaultValues[$attributeId] = $configValue;
                }
            }
        }

        $taxCalculation = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation');
        if (!$taxCalculation->getCustomer() && Mage::registry('current_customer')) {
            $taxCalculation->setCustomer(Mage::registry('current_customer'));
        }

        $_request = $taxCalculation->getRateRequest(false, false, false);
        $_request->setProductClassId($currentProduct->getTaxClassId());
        $defaultTax = $taxCalculation->getRate($_request);

        $_request = $taxCalculation->getRateRequest();
        $_request->setProductClassId($currentProduct->getTaxClassId());
        $currentTax = $taxCalculation->getRate($_request);

        $taxConfig = array(
            'includeTax'        => $taxHelper->priceIncludesTax(),
            'showIncludeTax'    => $taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax(),
            'showBothPrices'    => $taxHelper->displayBothPrices(),
            'defaultTax'        => $defaultTax,
            'currentTax'        => $currentTax,
            'inclTaxTitle'      => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Incl. Tax')
        );

        $config = array(
            'attributes'        => $attributes,
            'template'          => str_replace('%s', '#{price}', $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getOutputFormat()),
            'basePrice'         => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($currentProduct->getFinalPrice())),
            'oldPrice'          => $this->_registerJsPrice($this->_convertPrice($currentProduct->getPrice())),
            'productId'         => $currentProduct->getId(),
            'chooseText'        => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Choose an Option...'),
            'taxConfig'         => $taxConfig
        );

        if ($preconfiguredFlag && !empty($defaultValues)) {
            $config['defaultValues'] = $defaultValues;
        }

        $config = array_merge($config, $this->_getAdditionalConfig());

        return Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($config);
    }

}
```

cheers, 
adrian

Comment: i cannot under understand ... what is  your question??

Comment: a magento community extension overrides my code in a local extension. MDN -> SalesOrderPlanning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a  module configuration in Magento, which will aide in resolving the conflicts. You can use this configuration module in the module/extension etc. of Extension Y wherein you can also define the loading order of Extension Y. You need to be able to load Extension Y after Extension X. As Magento eCommerce website developers, when you are able to do this, you would have resolved the conflict well.Write below mentioned code to the depends module configuration in app/etc/modules/extension_Y.xml of Extension Y:

[image]

For more information check [ways-to-identify-and-resolve-magento-extension-conflicts](http://www.mconnectmedia.com/blog/ways-to-identify-and-resolve-magento-extension-conflicts/)

And moreover [resolving conflict](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3880/how-can-i-prevent-a-module-rewrite-class-conflict-in-magento)